# Refresh routed component when changing params

Tags: angular, angular-routing

When clicking on the "run report" button in a filters component,
I'm trying to navigate to a report result page using

```
this.router.navigate([this.getReportRouteByID()], {queryParams: {filters: JSON.stringify(this.filtersParamsData)}});
```

The problem is that when I change the set of selected values in the filters component - the report result page is not refereshing, meaning - it doesn't "take into considaration" the new set of filters. 
Currently the relevant code (running the report) in the "targeted" component is 
in the ngOnInit function. I've tried putting the code in the ngOnChanges function - but nothing happens.
See my code:
This is the function in the filters component (which I want to be execute whenever I change the selected filters and execute the  every change of the **runReport** function ):

```
runReport()
{
    this.filtersData.forEach (filter => this.populateFilterData (filter));
    let queryParameters : Params = this.filtersParamsData;

     this.router.navigate([this.getReportRouteByID()], {queryParams: 
     {filters: JSON.stringify(this.filtersParamsData)}});
```

}

This is the code in the "targeted" component:
**Originally - Wrong:**

```
ngOnInit() 
{
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((parameters : any) => 
    {
       this.reportSelectedFilters = JSON.parse(parameters.filters)
    });

    this.reportServiceService.setSelected...
}
```

**Fixed - Remove the ngOnInit and instead use the constructor:**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private reportServiceService : 
   ReportService, private phrases : Phrases  )  
{
   this.route.queryParams.subscribe((parameters : any) => 
    {
       this.reportSelectedFilters = JSON.parse(parameters.filters)
    //Set the report data also - whenever filters data change:
    this.reportServiceService.setREportData..
   });
}
```

and this is the (lean version) container of the filters component and the "targeted" components (the app-cadaster-report-filters is the filters component):

```
<div >
    <app-cadaster-report-filters [filtersData]='filters' [name]='reportName' 
  [reportID]='reportID' ></app-cadaster-report-filters>
</div>

<div class="router-outlet-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This is component code:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private filterService 
: FilterService) 
{
    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
   .subscribe((params:ParamMap) => {
    if (params.has("id"))
    {
      this.reportID = +params.get('id');


    var Report : Report = new Report(this.filterService, this.reportID); 
    Report.getFiltersData().subscribe(result => 
           this.setFilters(result), error => console.log);
  }
});
```

}

Comment: So, if I understand well, you are on a page like "/report?filters={}" and, inside the component of this route, you edit the query parameters like so : "/report?filters={filter1: 1}" and would like to refresh the page or run the function which parse the parameters?

Comment: @Kapcash -  correct - I run the page on the first time with a set of params (it runs OK) ,then - change the set of params and run the report again - but the component was already initialized - I'm looking for a life cycle event (on the target component) that would be triggered when running it again.